# MS Graph API - Java Application - Error during http request

Tags: java, http

I am trying to make consecutive calls to Graph API for changing device attributes and syncing the across Endpoint Manager and AAD.
I have the following 3 classes:

```
public class Runme {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        String tenantId = "MyTenant";
        String appId = "MyApp";
        String appSecret = "MyAppSecret";   
        DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager(tenantId, appId, appSecret);
        deviceManager.syncDeviceCategory();
        deviceManager.deleteStaleDevicesAad();      
    }
}
```

a wrapper for the graph client:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Device;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.DeviceCategory;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.ManagedDevice;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.DeviceCategoryCollectionPage;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.DeviceCollectionPage;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.DeviceCollectionRequestBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.ManagedDeviceCollectionPage;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentityCollectionPage;

import okhttp3.Request;

public class GraphWrapper {
    public GraphWrapper(String tenantId,String appId,String appSecret) {
        clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder().clientId(appId).clientSecret(appSecret).tenantId(tenantId).build();
        List<String> graphUserScopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        tokenCredAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(graphUserScopes, clientSecretCredential);
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(tokenCredAuthProvider).buildClient();
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Device> getAadDevices() {
        ArrayList<Device> aadDevices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        
        DeviceCollectionPage devicesPage = graphClient.devices().buildRequest().get();
        
        while (devicesPage != null) {
            final List<Device> devices = devicesPage.getCurrentPage();
            for ( Device dev : devices ) {
                aadDevices.add(dev);
            }
            final DeviceCollectionRequestBuilder nextPage = devicesPage.getNextPage();
              if (nextPage == null) {
                break;
              } else {
                  devicesPage = nextPage.buildRequest().get();
              }
        }
        aadDevices.trimToSize(); 
        System.out.println("AAD Devices: "+aadDevices.size());
        return aadDevices;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Device> getAadDevices2() {
        ArrayList<Device> aadDevices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        DeviceCollectionPage devices = null;
        boolean notFinished = true; 
        while ( notFinished ) {
            if ( devices == null ) {
                devices = graphClient.devices().buildRequest().get();
                for ( Device device : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                    aadDevices.add(device);
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    devices = devices.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                    for ( Device device : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                        aadDevices.add(device);
                    }   
                }
                catch (NullPointerException  e) {
                    notFinished = false;
                }
            }
        }
        aadDevices.trimToSize(); 
        System.out.println("AAD Devices: "+aadDevices.size());
        return aadDevices;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<ManagedDevice> getManagedDevices() { 
        ArrayList<ManagedDevice> managedDevices = new ArrayList<ManagedDevice>();
        ManagedDeviceCollectionPage devices = null;
        boolean notFinished = true; 
        while ( notFinished ) {
            if ( devices == null ) {
                devices = graphClient.deviceManagement().managedDevices().buildRequest().get();
                for ( ManagedDevice managedDevice : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                    managedDevices.add(managedDevice);
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    devices = devices.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                    for ( ManagedDevice managedDevice : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                        managedDevices.add(managedDevice);
                    }   
                }
                catch (NullPointerException  e) {
                    notFinished = false;
                }
            }
        }
        managedDevices.trimToSize(); 
        System.out.println("Managed Devices: "+managedDevices.size());
        return managedDevices;
    }
    
    
    public ArrayList<DeviceCategory> getManagedDeviceCategories() { 
        ArrayList<DeviceCategory> managedDeviceCategories = new ArrayList<DeviceCategory>();
        DeviceCategoryCollectionPage deviceCategories = null;
        boolean notFinished = true; 
        while ( notFinished ) {
            if ( deviceCategories == null ) {
                deviceCategories = graphClient.deviceManagement().deviceCategories().buildRequest().get();
                for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : deviceCategories.getCurrentPage() ) {
                    managedDeviceCategories.add(managedDeviceCategory);
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    deviceCategories = deviceCategories.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : deviceCategories.getCurrentPage() ) {
                        managedDeviceCategories.add(managedDeviceCategory);
                    }
                }
                catch (NullPointerException  e) {
                    notFinished = false;
                }
            }
        }
        managedDeviceCategories.trimToSize(); 
        System.out.println("Managed Devices Categories: "+managedDeviceCategories.size());
        return managedDeviceCategories;
    }
    
    
    
    
    public ArrayList<WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity> getAutopilotDevices() { 
        ArrayList<WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity> autopilotDevices = new ArrayList<WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity>();
        WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentityCollectionPage devices = null;
        boolean notFinished = true; 
        while ( notFinished ) {
            if ( devices == null ) {
                devices = graphClient.deviceManagement().windowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities().buildRequest().get();
                for ( WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity autopilotDevice : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                    autopilotDevices.add(autopilotDevice);
                }
            }
            else {
                try {
                    devices = devices.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
                    for ( WindowsAutopilotDeviceIdentity autopilotDevice : devices.getCurrentPage() ) {
                        autopilotDevices.add(autopilotDevice);
                    }   
                }
                catch (NullPointerException  e) {
                    notFinished = false;
                }
            }
        }
        autopilotDevices.trimToSize(); 
        System.out.println("Devs: "+autopilotDevices.size());
        
        return autopilotDevices;
    }
    public ClientSecretCredential getClientSecretCredential() {
        return clientSecretCredential;
    }

    public TokenCredentialAuthProvider getTokenCredAuthProvider() {
        return tokenCredAuthProvider;
    }

    public GraphServiceClient<Request> getGraphClient() {
        return graphClient;
    }
    private final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential;
    private final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredAuthProvider;
    private final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient;
}
```

And the class performing all the actions:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.Device;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.DeviceCategory;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.ManagedDevice;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.DeviceCategoryRequestBuilder;

public class DeviceManager {
    public DeviceManager(String tenantId,String appId,String appSecret) {
        setGraphWrapper( new GraphWrapper(tenantId, appId, appSecret) );
    }   
    public void syncDeviceCategory() { 
        ArrayList<ManagedDevice> manuallyConfigureDevicesAad = syncAadDeviceCategoryToManagedDeviceCategory();
        manuallyConfigureDeviceCategoryBasedOnUpn(manuallyConfigureDevicesAad);
        manuallyConfigureDevicesAad = syncAadDeviceCategoryToManagedDeviceCategory();
        manuallyConfigureDeviceCategoryBasedOnComputerName(manuallyConfigureDevicesAad);
        // These are the devices that we need to manually configure on InTune
        manuallyConfigureDevicesAad = syncAadDeviceCategoryToManagedDeviceCategory();
        for ( ManagedDevice d : manuallyConfigureDevicesAad ) {
            System.out.println(d.deviceName);
        }
        // Set device category to unmanaged AAD Devices 
        configureUnmanagedDevicesAad();
    }
    
    // Delete stale devices - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/manage-stale-devices
    public void deleteStaleDevicesAad() {
        ArrayList<Device> aadDevices = getGraphWrapper().getAadDevices();
        for ( Device device : aadDevices) {
            OffsetDateTime threshold = OffsetDateTime.now().minusMonths(6);
            OffsetDateTime lastHeartbeat = device.approximateLastSignInDateTime;
            boolean deviceIsStale = false; 
            
            System.out.println("What is the last update time? "+device.displayName);
            
            if ( lastHeartbeat.isBefore(threshold) ) {
                deviceIsStale = true;
            }
            
            java.util.List<String> physicalIds = device.physicalIds;
            boolean isAutopilot = false;
            found:
            for ( String physicalId : physicalIds ) {
                if ( physicalId.startsWith("[HWID]:") ) {
                    isAutopilot = true;
                    break found;
                }
            }
            if ( !isAutopilot && deviceIsStale ) {
                // DELETE THE DEVICE
                System.out.println("DELETE THE DEVICE? "+device.displayName);
                // getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient().devices(device.id).buildRequest().delete();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void configureUnmanagedDevicesAad() {
        ArrayList<Device> aadDevices = getGraphWrapper().getAadDevices();
        for ( Device device : aadDevices) {
            if ( device.deviceCategory == null ) {
                boolean isManaged = false; 
                try { 
                    isManaged = device.isManaged.booleanValue();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    isManaged = false;
                }
                if ( !isManaged ) {
                    Device deviceToUpdate = new Device();
                    System.out.println("check device name: "+device.displayName);
                    if ( device.displayName.length() > 3 && device.operatingSystem.equalsIgnoreCase("Windows") ) {
                        switch ( device.displayName.substring(0,3) ) {
                        case "a":
                            deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory = "IT Department of a";
                            System.out.println("~~~~ PATCHING Unmanaged AAD DEVICE "+device.displayName+" with "+deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory);
                            getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient().devices(device.id).buildRequest().patch(deviceToUpdate);
                            break;
                        case "b":
                            deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory = "IT Department of b";
                            System.out.println("~~~~ PATCHING Unmanaged AAD DEVICE "+device.displayName+" with "+deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory);
                            getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient().devices(device.id).buildRequest().patch(deviceToUpdate);
                            break;
                        case "a":
                            deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory = "IT Department of a";
                            System.out.println("~~~~ PATCHING Unmanaged AAD DEVICE "+device.displayName+" with "+deviceToUpdate.deviceCategory);
                            getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient().devices(device.id).buildRequest().patch(deviceToUpdate);
                            break;
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void manuallyConfigureDeviceCategoryBasedOnComputerName(ArrayList<ManagedDevice> manuallyConfigureDevicesAad) {
        ArrayList<DeviceCategory> managedDeviceCategories = getGraphWrapper().getManagedDeviceCategories();
        for ( ManagedDevice managedDevice : manuallyConfigureDevicesAad ) {
            String deviceCategoryId = null;
            String deviceCategoryDisplayName;   
            if ( managedDevice.deviceName != null && !managedDevice.deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("") ) {
                switch ( managedDevice.deviceName.substring(0,3) ) {
                case "a":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of a";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "b":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of b";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "a":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of a";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if ( deviceCategoryId != null ) {
                    System.out.println("Seeting DEVICE CATEGORY "+deviceCategoryId+" to "+managedDevice.deviceName);
                    DeviceCategory deviceCategory = new DeviceCategory();
                    deviceCategory.additionalDataManager().put("@odata.id", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/"+deviceCategoryId));
                    new DeviceCategoryRequestBuilder("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/"+managedDevice.id+"/deviceCategory/$ref", getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient(),null).buildRequest().put(deviceCategory);  
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    
    public void manuallyConfigureDeviceCategoryBasedOnUpn(ArrayList<ManagedDevice> manuallyConfigureDevicesAad) {
        ArrayList<DeviceCategory> managedDeviceCategories = getGraphWrapper().getManagedDeviceCategories();
        
        for ( ManagedDevice managedDevice : manuallyConfigureDevicesAad ) {
            String deviceCategoryId = null;
            String deviceCategoryDisplayName;
            if ( managedDevice.userPrincipalName != null && !managedDevice.userPrincipalName.equalsIgnoreCase("") ) {
                switch (managedDevice.userPrincipalName.substring(managedDevice.userPrincipalName.indexOf("@")+1)) {
                case "c":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of c";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "b":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of b";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "a":
                    deviceCategoryDisplayName = "IT Department of a";
                    found: 
                    for ( DeviceCategory managedDeviceCategory : managedDeviceCategories ) {
                        if ( managedDeviceCategory.displayName.equalsIgnoreCase(deviceCategoryDisplayName)  ) {
                            deviceCategoryId = managedDeviceCategory.id;
                            break found;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Setting DEVICE CATEGORY "+deviceCategoryId+" to "+managedDevice.deviceName);
                DeviceCategory deviceCategory = new DeviceCategory();
                deviceCategory.additionalDataManager().put("@odata.id", new JsonPrimitive("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/"+deviceCategoryId));
                new DeviceCategoryRequestBuilder("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/"+managedDevice.id+"/deviceCategory/$ref", getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient(),null).buildRequest().put(deviceCategory);
            }       
        }       
    }
    
    public ArrayList<ManagedDevice> syncAadDeviceCategoryToManagedDeviceCategory() { 
        ArrayList<Device> aadDevices = getGraphWrapper().getAadDevices();
        ArrayList<ManagedDevice> managedDevices = getGraphWrapper().getManagedDevices();    
        ArrayList<ManagedDevice> managedDeviceToManuallyConfigure = new ArrayList<ManagedDevice>();
        for ( Device aadDevice : aadDevices ) {
            for ( ManagedDevice managedDevice : managedDevices ) {
                ManagedDevice toManuallyConfigure = checkAndSyncDeviceCategoryFromManagedDevice(aadDevice,managedDevice);
                if ( toManuallyConfigure != null ) {
                    managedDeviceToManuallyConfigure.add(toManuallyConfigure);
                }
            }
        }
        return managedDeviceToManuallyConfigure;
    } 
    
    private ManagedDevice checkAndSyncDeviceCategoryFromManagedDevice(Device aadDevice,ManagedDevice managedDevice) {
        ManagedDevice found = null;
        if ( aadDevice.deviceId.equals(managedDevice.azureADDeviceId) ) {
            String aadDeviceCategory = aadDevice.deviceCategory;
            String managedDeviceCategory = managedDevice.deviceCategoryDisplayName;
            if ( aadDeviceCategory == null ) {
                if ( managedDeviceCategory != null) {
                    if ( !managedDeviceCategory.equalsIgnoreCase("Unknown") ) {
                        Device device = new Device();
                        device.deviceCategory = managedDeviceCategory;
                        System.out.println("~~~~ PATCHING AAD DEVICE ~~~~");
                        System.out.println(aadDevice.displayName+ " with category: "+managedDeviceCategory);
                        getGraphWrapper().getGraphClient().devices(aadDevice.id).buildRequest().patch(device);
                    }
                    else {
                        found = managedDevice;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    found = managedDevice;
                }
            }   
        }
        return found;
    }
    
    public GraphWrapper getGraphWrapper() {
        return graphWrapper;
    }

    public void setGraphWrapper(GraphWrapper graphWrapper) {
        this.graphWrapper = graphWrapper;
    }
    private GraphWrapper graphWrapper;
}
```

When I run the code I get the following exception:

```
Aug 18, 2022 2:00:10 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Error during http request
Aug 18, 2022 2:00:10 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:494)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:408)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:225)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:202)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseCollectionRequest.send(BaseCollectionRequest.java:103)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseEntityCollectionRequest.get(BaseEntityCollectionRequest.java:78)
    at com.consumeit.GraphWrapper.getAadDevices(GraphWrapper.java:46)
    at com.consumeit.DeviceManager.syncAadDeviceCategoryToManagedDeviceCategory(DeviceManager.java:583)
    at com.consumeit.DeviceManager.syncDeviceCategory(DeviceManager.java:16)
    at com.consumeit.Runme.main(Runme.java:12)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1073)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:986)
    at com.microsoft.graph.serializer.DefaultSerializer.deserializeObject(DefaultSerializer.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleJsonResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:538)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.processResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:467)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okio.SocketAsyncTimeout.newTimeoutException(JvmOkio.kt:147)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout.access$newTimeoutException(AsyncTimeout.kt:158)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:337)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.kt:206)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.kt:199)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.kt:381)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:429)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1ExchangeCodec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1ExchangeCodec.kt:408)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.kt:276)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:189)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.kt:197)
    at okio.InflaterSource.refill(InflaterSource.kt:112)
    at okio.InflaterSource.readOrInflate(InflaterSource.kt:76)
    at okio.InflaterSource.read(InflaterSource.kt:49)
    at okio.GzipSource.read(GzipSource.kt:69)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$inputStream$1.read(RealBufferedSource.kt:158)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1300)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextQuotedValue(JsonReader.java:1040)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$28.readTerminal(TypeAdapters.java:720)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$28.read(TypeAdapters.java:764)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$28.read(TypeAdapters.java:698)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$34$1.read(TypeAdapters.java:979)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1058)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:280)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:800)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:966)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1059)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:94)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$source$1.read(AsyncTimeout.kt:125)
    ... 40 more
```

It seems that I am getting an HTTP 408 eventhough I am creating a single instance of HTTP pool that makes the requests.
I would really appreciate any help on overcomming the error.